# Facebook iOS sdk 3.2 post to wall without FBWebDialogResult

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I would like to post to user's wall without showing a pop up just like FBWebDialogResult do. I have used the SDK to login and have user permission to publish to wall. Is this possible with using Facebook SDK? or Should I use graph API?

I tried this,

`[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" 
                    andParams:fbArguments
                andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                  andDelegate:self];`

but it's no longer working in iOS Facebook SDK 3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use:

```
[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"feed" parameters:fbArguments HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {}];
```

Found here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/3.2/class/FBRequestConnection#startWithGraphPath%3Aparameters%3AHTTPMethod%3AcompletionHandler%3A